Connecting chrome-ux-report dataset in BigQuery via service account
I can access chrome-ux-report via BigQuery UI which is fine.
But I would connect to the dataseta chrome-ux-report via service account, trought 3rd-party-connectors or 3rd-party BigQuery client (such as DataGrip).
Do you have ever tried to connect chrome-ux-report via service account? Any chance to do it?
I can setup a monthly transfer query, which is already in place, but it is consuming a lot of credit, so it is not sustainable for the project I am aiming to.
The service account I am using has the major roles I can grant for bigQuery (Admin, Editor, Viewer, User), but I cannot acces the data directly in read mode.
